# Why is upper half of circle not showing

Tags: html, svg

I have a p tag inside a div right above an svg canvas with a circle but the I'm only showing the lower half of the circle. Should't the y center coordinate start 20 px down the canvas?

```
  <body>
    <div id="header">
        <p>Is this a circle?</p>
    </div>
    <svg width="500px" height="40px">
        <circle r="20" cx="50" yx="20" />
    </svg>
    <div class="footer">
        <p>Yeah, looks like it</p>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have misspelled an attribute in your SVG code:

```
<circle r="20" cx="50" yx="20" />
                    /* ^^^ It should be cy */
```

If `cy` attribute is missing, its default value i.e `0` will be used. So that's why half of the circle is outside of the viewport area and its invisible.

Here is the correct variant:

```
<circle r="20" cx="50" cy="20" />
```

```html
<div id="header">
    <p>Is this a circle?</p>
</div>
<svg width="500px" height="40px">
    <circle r="20" cx="50" cy="20" />
</svg>
<div class="footer">
    <p>Yeah, looks like it</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This could have been a comment and a vote to close a typo

Comment: Thank you. What a fail on my part. LOL!